# Difference between pcm and ctl in alsa ~/.asoundrc

Tags: sound, alsa

I need to write an `~/.asoundrc` file to configure some Audio devices because I need to be able to select single channels from these devices.

Because I am not very experienced with alsa I started to look for an [Introduction to the subject](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc). It states that a basic `.asoundrc` file looks something like this:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw           
    card 0
}
```

But I don't know what the `ctl` option is used for. What I have found in the [ALSA Documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Alternative_method) still doesn't explain it to me clearly:

> The 'pcm' options affect which card and device will be used for audio playback while the 'ctl' option affects which card is used by control utilities like alsamixer .

What is the difference between `pcm` and `ctl`? What is their purpose? When to use which one?

---

**Update**
I am now able to play different audio streams on the same device but over two different channels:

```
pcm.USB_hw{
    type hw
    format S16_LE
    rate 48000
    card 2
    device 0
    subdevice 0
    channels 2
}

pcm.USB_dmix{
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1111
    slave.pcm "USB_hw"

    hint {
        description "Direct sample mixing device"
    }
}

pcm.OUTPUT0 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type route
        slave.pcm "USB_dmix"

        ttable{
            0.0 0
            1.1 1
        }

        hint {
            description "Playback channel 0 over USB"
        }
    }
}

pcm.OUTPUT1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type route
        slave.pcm "USB_dmix"

        ttable {
            0.0 1
            1.1 0
        }

        hint {
            description "Playback channel 1 over USB"
        }
    }
}
```

It works alright, but I cannot access the volume of these plugins (`OUTPUT0` and `OUTPUT1`) in the `alsamixer`. This access is probably configured in the `ctl` options, which I have never used yet.

The question is how to configure `ctl` so these plugs will be shown in the `alsamixer`?
Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you know what is meant with "audio playback" and "alsamixer"?

Comment: @CL. I assume the "audio playback" is the music that I can hear from the speakers, and "alsamixer" is the small program which controls stuff like the volume, etc?

Comment: Yes. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @CL. I updated the question. It's about how to configure the ctl options. Is it the same as in the pcm options?

Comment: These plugins do not have a dynamic volume setting. You'd have to add `softvol` plugins.

Comment: @CL. Thanks for the hint, I did that and everything works fine now. But I have never used the `ctl` option to achieve any of my goals. I still can't see the purpose of `ctl`. Because I can access `alsamixer` with `pcm`, does that mean the `ctl` option is useless/unnecessary?

Comment: There is no `ctl` plugin except `hw`, and `card` is the only option. It's useful only if you want to change this option.